# 'TypeError: oColumn is undefined' when setting bStateSave to true in Datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I've been using Datatables for just a bit now. I need to set the `bStateSave` variable to true to save the pagination length from the previous load.  When I do this, I get a

> TypeError: oColumn is undefined'

I've tried a number of things; no luck so far.

Here's the markup; I made it a very basic table:

```
<table border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="3" id="system_statuses_table" class="display">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th><strong><font size="2">System</font></strong></th>
      <th><strong><font size="2">Status</font></strong></th>
      <th><strong><font size="2">Notes</font></strong></th>
      <th><strong><font size="2">Environment</font></strong></th>
      <th><strong><font size="2">Project</font></strong></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>System Value</td>
      <td>Status Value</td>
      <td>Notes Value</td>
      <td>Environment Value</td>
      <td>Project Value</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

  <script>
    Ext.onReady(function() {


      $j('#my_table').dataTable({
          "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
          "bStateSave": true
      });


    });
  </script>
```

As soon as I change bStateSave to false, I do not get the error.

Comment: show your markup  impossible to guess

Comment: Ext.onReady(function() {   
  
   $j('#system_statuses_table').dataTable({
          "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
   });
});

Comment: any more suggestions?  It happens the moment I set bStateSave to true.  Thanks, Tim

Comment: Your code works perfectly here (of course after changing `id="system_statuses_table"` to `id="my_table"`) - works both with `"bStateSave": true` and `"bStateSave": false`

Comment: `oColumn is undefined` is typically raised when there is mismatch between thad / tbody, you lack thead, lack tbody, has moltiple tbodys and so on. And would be raised when datatables try to save the state of the table. But the above table is not malformed.

Comment: So has this ever happened to anyone else?  The weird thing is I get this in two separate web sites.